# Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

to show map I use [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps). I did all config but when run my project get the following message in the console:

> Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values.
> Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
> Require cycle:
> node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\components\MapView.js ->
> node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\components\Geojson.js ->
> node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\components\MapView.js

I think this message causes a problem and does not allow the app to show the map.
How can I solve this?

```
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps'
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <MapView
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
            style={styles.map}
            region={{
              latitude: 37.78825,
              longitude: -122.4324,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}
          >
          </MapView>
        </View>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this issue using an answer in [this Github issue](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/3352) by itsam, with my more detailed instructions in the brackets, assuming you are at your root directory where `package.json` is:

> 1. install patch-package (`npm i -D patch-package` or `yarn add -D patch-package`).
> 2. create a folder in your project called "patches" (`mkdir patches`)
> 3. Inside "patches" folder get the patch from this gist (for convenience) https://gist.github.com/itsam/278a56a1f20a8b80e27c269d9fe83093
>    and name it as react-native-maps+0.27.1.patch (copy and paste the contents of the patch file in the gist URL to `patches/react-native-maps+0.27.1.patch`)
> 4. In `package.json`, include `"postinstall": "patch-package"` under `script`(The writer forgot to include this important step)
> 5. `yarn install` or `npm install` (it may throw a warning saying that the versions are mismatched, but it works for me)

Comment: nicely worked without show any warnings. thanks for your post and your complete answer to fix the cycle error on react-native-maps. @Alex_Zhong